# fabric traceback: ImportError: cannot import name cd

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

Hello I am trying to learn fabric thought it may be useful and so I was following along the test script I should say or test fab command in the book "The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Python!" might be a little out of date since it asked me to do 'from fabric.api" but I fixed that problem now I am getting a import error which I dont understand why could be something with new version of fabric perhaps but the error is a trace back

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from fabric import cd,env,prefix,run,task
ImportError: cannot import name 'cd'
```

here is the code, cut and pasted from notepad++
also you will see the r by  with cd(r'blah blah b;ah')
that was because I was getting a unicode error and a google search said that was the fix
in any case I hope you can help ,me or direct me to somewhere that can

```
#import fabric
from fabric.api import cd,env,prefix,run,task

#where you are running the data on
env.host = [' 192.168.6.29']

#first fab task will be checking all free memory in linux
@task
def memory_usage():
    run('Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | fl *')

#second task will deploy this making it a fab file  
@task 
def deploy():
    with cd(r'C:\Users\JayBhatt'):
        with prefix('.../bin/activate'):
            run('git pull')
            run('touch app-wsgi')
```

Comment: Probably a `bytes` object would be better: either `.encode('utf-8')` or `b'some_string'`.

Comment: I will consider that going forward I was just following the example in the book to get a feel of fabric

Answer (score 0):

from fabric import * fixed this issue